# How do i make a div box change colors when hover overed?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make a white div box turn red when it's hover overed, so far i have this in my css:

```
#white{
width: 90px;
height: 90 px;
background-color:white;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left:10px;
}


a:hover #white{
color:red;
width: 90px;
height: 90 px;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left:10px;
}
```

and this in my html:

```
<div id="white">
</div>
```

but it doesn't work at all, help please?

Answer (score 3):

You need to go back and read a bit more about HTML and CSS basics.

1. You are targeting a link that doesn't exist.
2. You don't set a background color for the hover state, so how could it change? You change the TEXT color, but not the background, and your question says you want to change the color of the
3. You have a space between 90 and px, so that breaks your CSS.

Something like this is probably what you want: [Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jvwfh)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `a:hover #white`, you're targeting an `<a>` tag that is being hovered with a child that has `id="white"`.

You want to use this:

```
#white:hover {
  ...
}
```

You're also on the hover event you're using `color` and not `background-color`.

http://jsfiddle.net/xuj44/1/

Comment: Just note that the legacy browser support for the `:hover` pseudo selector on things other than `<a>` tags is limited.  Modern browsers should do just fine, though.

Comment: I don't know about that @JonathanNewmuis. According to caniuse.com it has had full support since IE7. IE6 is partial support but no one should be developing for IE6 anymore really, the market share is tiny. http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahover

Comment: change your color:red to background-color and yes

Comment: @Tyriar `:hover` has had support since IE7, but not on tags other than `<a>` and not for certain doctypes.  But in the end, it boils down to the obvious: test your solution in every browser that's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered but it seems like you are trying to run before you can walk, http://w3schools.com/ is possibly where every front-end web developer began learning html/css - it will give you the basic fundamentals of the language so its well worth reading through each section. Even seasons developers have to pop back to it occasionally just to jog there memory. Good luck, and keep trying :)

Comment: Obligatory "don't send people to w3schools.com". I don't hate it as much as some people; for people who know what they are doing and can tell where they are dead wrong it's not the worst site. However, for beginners, they need to know that site is riddled with errors.